# What's the difference between cimi and cim

Tags: authorize.net-cim

I am reading some articles on dmtf.org.But I am confused by some concepts.
What is Cloud Infrastructure Management Interface(CIMI)? I don't find the defintion of the logical model of CIMI.
What is Common Information Model(CIM)?
And what's the relationship between them?

Anybody helps? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The CIMI standard of the DMTF defines a REStful protocol and a model for cloud infrastructure management; both is defined in [DSP0263](http://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0263_1.0.pdf).

The CIM standard of the DMTF is a much broader model for IT management, it is defined as a "CIM Schema" in a language called MOF, and on top of that using so called management profiles that use classes from the CIM Schema for specific purposes.

The CIMI standard has been defined such that it does not use the CIM standard, but works standalone, for simplicity. However, there is also a mapping of CIMI into the CIM Schema, which is defined in [DSP0264](http://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0264_1.0.pdf). This provides an alternative way to implement the logical model of CIMI, using the technology of CIM.

So there are two independent ways of implementing and consuming CIMI:
1. standalone, as defined in DSP0263. This is the choice if you want simplicity.
2. through CIM technology, as defined in DSP0264 and the CIM Schema. This is the choice if you have invested in CIM technology already and want to leverage that.

A particular implementation of CIMI could choose one or even implement both at the same time.

Note that CIM allows to manage many more areas than just cloud. Popular areas include storage (SMI-S, defined by SNIA), servers (SMASH, defined by DMTF), system virtualization (VMAN, defined by DMTF), desktop (DASH, defined by DMTF).

Andy